# How to test SSL configuration on a site in different deployment environemnts

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

I have an ASP.NET website that fails when SSL is configured and turned on. The site is deployed in a an environment that i have no access to, so i can't test nor troubleshoot from that environment. However, i can get the same source code deployed in an a different environment that i have full access to.

Is it possible to have the same problematic SSL configuration/settings duplicated in these two different environments so i can do some real troubleshooting of what exactly might be wrong.

As it currently is, all i know is that when SSL is turned on, the site stops working. When turned off, the site works fine but i can't reproduce that behavior in my environment is there a better way i should be approaching this troubleshooting?

Remembers, i am talking about IIS 6 here.

Answer (score 0):

Following this article and the links provided in it meets my requirements.
https://www.scantosecure.com/blog/preparing-your-development-environment-for-ssl